# APDropDownNavToolbar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to implement the `APDropDownNavToolbar` in a swift project.
I came pretty far, until I ran the simulator.
It gives me a `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at the line where the toolbar items should be initialising the `UIBarButtons`.

I also can't manage to get the setup of the DropDownView in Swift:

```
`self.navController = (APNavigationController*)self.navigationController;`
```

Here is the objc code [APDropDownNavToolbar](https://github.com/ankurp/APDropDownNavToolbar/blob/master/Demo/DropDownToolBar/APViewController.m)

This is my translation so far:

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {

var navController = APNavigationController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ........

    self.navController.activeBarButtonTitle = ""
    self.navController.activeNavigationBarTitle = ""
}

@IBAction func navBarTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navController.dropDownToolbar.items = [[UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)],
                                                [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit, target: self, action: "editClicked:")],
                                                [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "actionClicked:")]]

    if (self.navController.isDropDownVisible)
    {
        self.navController.hideDropDown(sender)

    }else{

        self.navController.showDropDown(sender)
    }
}

func editClicked(){
    println("edit Button clicked")
}

func actionClicked(){
    println("action Buttonclicked")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your [Array] is fine.

Perhaps your dropDownToolbar is declared as optional or nil in APNavigationController?